# Disable propagation of click handle to child in vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using this markup

```
<div @click='handleClickOnDiv'>
    {{ message }}
    <i class='fa fa-plus' @click='handleClickOnI'></i>
</div>
```

When I click on `div` - it calls `handleClickOnDiv`, but when I click on `i` - it calls both handlers.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 8):

Try [Event-Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) with `@click`, you can do following:

```
<div @click='handleClickOnDiv'>
    {{ message }}
    <i class='fa fa-plus' @click.stop='handleClickOnI'></i>
</div>
```